# Broadcom BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n wireless adapter stopped working on update

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Acer laptop (Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n) and everything was just fine.
In some point (maybe after I installed some updates) the wireless adapter stopped working.
There are lots of people have this problem too, but I looked through lots of answers and still not working. re-installing the bcmwl-kernel-source didn't work either.
what should I do
Thanks

Comment: Please run the command lspci -nn and edit your question to add the wireless card details.

Comment: Please at least link to the posts you read so people have a reference.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem, it was resolved by following the steps here

http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/10/how-to-fix-unity-and-wireless-problems.html

**WiFi Stops Working After Upgrading To Ubuntu 12.10 (Broadcom Wireless cards)**

You can fix wifi problems using two methods:

- Either connect to the internet via wired connection and run this command:

  `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Then reboot your system.

- Or use the following commands:

  `sudo apt-get install linux linux-headers-generic kernel-package`

  `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl* firmware-b43-lpphy-installer b43-fwcutter`

Finally, reboot your system.

If that didn't help, try these commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source

sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter

sudo reboot
```

Good luck.